# ld: framework not found Fabric for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-fabric

I want to remove fabric sdk & implementation which i have used in my project but i getting `ld: framework not found Fabric for architecture x86_64`issue.

I really does not understand why i am getting this issue even after i am following bellow steps,

1. Removed all code related to fabric from my project
2. Removed framework from project navigator
3. Deleted run script from target build phase
4. Deleted derived data
5. Cleaned project
6. Restart xcode

Impact i have crosschecked framework search path also that weather any fabric reference is present but i have not found any reference there.

Can anybody help me to fix this?

Comment: Have you installed the Mac app?

Comment: Yes i i have previously but deleted now.

Comment: It need the desktop app to work

Comment: Bro, can you read first line please? i want to remove fabric implementation. I don't think there is relation with app. Still i have installed it again. Not working.

Comment: @Tj3n i found bug & got solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got irony,

Fabric removed Twitter kit from latest version of fabric, Still i was using twitter kit frameworks which was generated & added manually in my project from fabric. So i removed it. And re-install TwitterKit through pod. Now everything working fine.